# Deleting a binary tree using inorder traversal

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I was learning how to delete a binary tree using Postorder traversal. I understand that to delete a node, first we need to delete its child node and then the node itself, so Postorder traversal is the best fit to delete a binary tree. I thought of doing the same using Inorder traversal, everything works fine but I don't understand how the below code works?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct b_tree{
    int data;
    struct b_tree *left,*right;
};

typedef struct b_tree tree;

tree* create_node(int data)
{
    struct b_tree* new_node=(tree*)malloc(sizeof(tree));
    new_node->data=data;
    new_node->left=NULL;
    new_node->right=NULL;
    return new_node;
}

void delete_tree(tree *root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    delete_tree(root->left);
    printf("Deleting %d node.\n",root->data);
    free(root);
    delete_tree(root->right);
}

int main()
{
    tree *root=NULL;
    root=create_node(1);
    root->left=create_node(2);
    root->right=create_node(3);
    root->left->left=create_node(4);
    root->left->right=create_node(5);
    root->left->right->left=create_node(6);
    root->left->right->right=create_node(7);
    root->right->right=create_node(8);
    root->right->right->left=create_node(9);
    delete_tree(root);
    root=NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Tree]
**According to Inorder traversal first node to be deleted is `4` and after that `2`, but once we freed `2` it should loose all it's data, means it should not retain the pointer to right node as well which is `5`, but even after `2` is freed its left child `5` is still traversed but it should not happen because node `2` is already freed.**
 

The output of the above code is:
[image: Output]
I was expecting the output to be in the following order of nodes: `4 2 1`.
I don't understand how all this is working. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The code is great for traversing (i.e.. reading) the tree, but watch out when deleting - you have "free(root)" followed by "delete_tree(root->right);", so you're accessing "root->right" AFTER deleting "root".

Comment: what did you expect `delete_tree(root->right)` to do, if not delete the right subtree?

Comment: I agree with what you guys said but what I'm trying to ask it that once `2` is freed, it should loose all its data, which ,means it should also loose pointer to right child as well which is `5`, but even after freeing `2` it is still able to access `5`, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally posted this as a comment but it seems the guy asking the question was happy with my answer so I will post it in a bit more detail here.

When calling free it is important to note EXACTLY what free actually does otherwise things like this can happen.

> The C library function void free(void *ptr) deallocates the memory previously allocated by a call to calloc, malloc, or realloc.

Note that the free function does NOT change the value of the pointer it simply gives the memory back to OS so that it can be allocated to another program. As such it is typical for people to "clear" the pointer after calling free to avoid accessing memory that another program has changed.

```
root = VOID;
```

The code above does not clear the root node after freeing it as such the memory is still all there. As such the C code is able to go to that memory location (which the OS has already received) and modify it. This is EXTREMELY dangerous behaviour because the OS can give this memory to another program and then your program could change causing obviously unexpected behaviour. The simple fix for this would be to remove the right node before freeing the root node.

Answer (score 1):

The output it shows is correct , because in inorder it first traverse `left sub-tree` then `root` and then `right sub-tree`.

You won't get `4 2 1` because `4` is left sub-tree then it goes to `root` that is `2` and then to right sub-tree of `2`.

When it goes too right sub-tree root becomes `5` and its left sub-tree is `6`.Then `5` and then to right sub-tree of `5` that is `7`.

`1` is the root so without traversing left sub-tree it won't go to `1`.

Comment: I understood what you answered but according the below algo first it should free(root) which is `2` and after that it should move towards 5 but once `2` is free how it can move towards 5 because the data of 2 is freed.
    `delete_tree(root->left);
     printf("Deleting %d node.\n",root->data);
     free(root);
     delete_tree(root->right);`

Comment: I think that `free(root)` is not placed correctly because it would free the root and loose track of right sub-tree. It should be `delete_tree(root->left);delete_tree(root->right);printf("Deleting %d node.\n",root->data); free(root); `

Comment: But if we use that then it would be Postorder traversal but here I'm talking about Inorder traversal.

Answer (score 1):

To traverse a binary tree in Inorder, following operations are carried-out

```
(i) Traverse the left most subtree starting at the left external node, 
(ii) Visit the root, and 
(iii) Traverse the right subtree starting at the left external node.
```

Now to delete the nodes,

```
(i) Traverse the left most subtree starting at the left external node,
(ii) delete the root, and 
(iii) Traverse the right subtree starting at the left external node.
```

Comment: I agree with your answer but what I'm trying to ask it that once `2` is freed, it should loose all its data, which ,means it should also loose pointer to right child which is `5`, but even after freeing `2` it is still able to access `5`, how?

Comment: You can save address of right child of **2** before deleting **2**. It should be quite easy. :) @AmanshuKataria

Comment: Ok, that would also work the same way, but my question is how is this working? :D
Too confusing. LOL

Comment: To answer his actual question of why does it work.
"The C library function void free(void *ptr) deallocates the memory previously allocated by a call to calloc, malloc, or realloc."
Now I could be wrong in saying this but I believe that free does NOT actually clear the value of the pointer normally that is up to the user. As such it is common practice to set a pointer to 0 or VOID once freed. Your code doesn't do this which means you still have access to where root is pointing. Free has told the OS it can be used again but you still have access to it. This code is very dangerous.

Comment: @arduic haha thank god! at least someone understood my question. I finally got answer to my question. You should post it as answer.

Comment: Glad you liked it I posted the answer below accept if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void delete_tree(tree *root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    delete_tree(root->left);
    printf("Deleting %d node.\n",root->data);
    free(root);
    delete_tree(root->right);
}
```

It is an inorder traversal where  pointer will first point to left most node, then root and then right most node. Since 4 is the left most node so it has been printed then it traverse to 2 . After which the right most node which is 5. Since 5 has two nodes attached to it. It will again iterate to left most node which is 6. So it printed as 4,2,6,5,7,3,9,8